# Convertir html a xml texto plano

Tags: html, python, xml, blogger

Buen dia, Estoy buscando la forma de poder convertir codigo html a xml pero en el formato que usa blogger. Dejo ejemplo.

HTML

```
<div class="card-headline"><h3 class="card-title">
```

XML en texto plano usado en las copias de seguridad de blogger

```
&lt;div class=&quot;card-headline&quot;&gt;&lt;h3 class=&quot;card-title&quot;&gt;
```

investigue y encontre que se usa chilkat o chilkat2 para convertir, Pero no me da el resultado que busco. Espero me puedan ayudar gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer esa conversión puedes usar *escape* del módulo *html*:

```
import html

print(html.escape('<div class="card-headline"><h3 class="card-title">'))
```

Lo que hace es remplazar "&", "<", ">" (y si el parámetro *quote* de la función
es *True*, también las comillas dobles y comillas simples) por las entidades
HTML correspondientes ("&amp;", "&lt;" y "&gt;". Ademas
"&quot;" y "&#x27;" si *quote* es *True*).